# Figure out the percentage of change on a chart over time

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

What's the principle of calculating growth/decay percentage if I have a set of numbers in an array, just like `[20,10,50,90,100]`? Look at the percentage changes on the image to get the idea of what I want to calculate.

Is it enough just to get first and last values and compare them, or do I need to find an average of all values with some formula?

[image: Chart]